# PaperType Variable for Windows Printer Queue

Tags: .net, powershell, printing, queue

This other question started to ask my question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx

If anyone else reads this, the original ask was for a PaperType variable, which should be something like plain, label, preprinted, etc...

I used powershell to see the .net, but i still cannot find PaperType, although, it seems to show me everything else... :-( As stated in the linked question, WMI does have a Current/Default PaperType, but its blank.

WHat i would like to do: Take an existing print queue, copy variables: Name, Default Tray, Duplex, Comment, PaperType. Change the driver, and set the variables back. I have all working, except for paperType.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$Printer = new-object System.Drawing.Printing.PRinterSettings 
$Printer | GM
```

output:

```
Name

Clone
CreateMeasurementGraphics Equals
GetHashCode
GetHdevmode
GetHdevnames
GetType
IsDirectPrintingSupported SetHdevmode
SetHdevnames
ToString
CanDuplex
Collate
Copies
DefaultPageSettings
Duplex
FromPage
IsDefaultPrinter
IsPlotter
IsValid
LandscapeAngle
MaximumCopies
MaximumPage
MinimumPage
PaperSizes
PaperSources
PrinterName
PrinterResolutions
PrintFileName
PrintRange
PrintToFile
SupportsColor
ToPage
```

---

```
$Printer.DefaultPageSettings
```

---

```
Name

Clone
CreateMeasurementGraphics Equals
GetHashCode
GetHdevmode
GetHdevnames
GetType
IsDirectPrintingSupported SetHdevmode
SetHdevnames
ToString
CanDuplex
Collate
Copies
DefaultPageSettings
Duplex
FromPage
IsDefaultPrinter
IsPlotter
IsValid
LandscapeAngle
MaximumCopies
MaximumPage
MinimumPage
PaperSizes
PaperSources
PrinterName
PrinterResolutions
PrintFileName
PrintRange
PrintToFile
SupportsColor
ToPage
```

---

```
$Printer.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings
```

---

```
Name

Clone
CreateMeasurementGraphics Equals
GetHashCode
GetHdevmode
GetHdevnames
GetType
IsDirectPrintingSupported SetHdevmode
SetHdevnames
ToString
CanDuplex
Collate
Copies
DefaultPageSettings
Duplex
FromPage
IsDefaultPrinter
IsPlotter
IsValid
LandscapeAngle
MaximumCopies
MaximumPage
MinimumPage
PaperSizes
PaperSources
PrinterName
PrinterResolutions
PrintFileName
PrintRange
PrintToFile
SupportsColor
ToPage
```

Comment: [System.Printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing(v=vs.110).aspx) has `PageMediaType`. Here is [a module](https://github.com/BenHimsel/PSPrintTools/tree/master/PSPrintTools) where `Get-PSPTPrintConfiguration` and `Set-PSPTPrintConfiguration` utilize it.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the reply. It looks like your scripts have the ability to find the media type supported and the ability to set the pagemediatype, but i need to be able to get the current pagemediatype that is configured. (in order to migrate it). 
I did find it buried in the Get-PrintConfiguration command. Save that output to a variable and do a $var.PrintTicketXML, its usually around the last line in that very long variable. But there must be a much cleaner/simpler way to get it?

Comment: `Win8` and newer you can grab that `PrintTicketXML` with the `Get-PrintConfiguration`. Otherwise grabbing the `System.Printing.PrintQueue` object for the printer there is a property called `DefaultPrintTicket` and `UserPrintTicket` which have the `PageMediaType` property if you don't want to parse the XML.

Comment: Ahh thats great, however, its showing me and "unknown" PageMediaType.  This must be related to why when i run GetPrintCapabilities().PageMediaTypeCapability, it doesnt actually show me all the paper types that the GUI shows me. Maybe this is related to the propriety settings of the bin file?   FYI, the GUI shows me that "PrePrinted" is selected.  Looks like my only option is parsing the XML? I dont really understand why, but i can make that work.

Comment: System.printing is pretty terrible. If it doesn't fall as a type in [its very limited enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.pagemediatype(v=vs.110).aspx) it shows as unknown and the xml is the way to see it. (And as a consequence you can't set a property to unknown, so if you need to set that property then you'll need to set using the xml as well).

Comment: So ive been noticing.  FYI, b/c of the migration parameters, im able to build multiple .bin files and associate the queue to that instead of actually settings values one by one. Its a round about way, but actually pretty effective for this project. Thank you!